# making a simple plugin

Tags: plugins, javascript

I'm new to coding, but not to wp.
If you point me in the right direction I will study what I need to reach the goal.

The goal is this: To build a very basic plugin.

It presents users with a forced choice question on the page (A or B or C), and based on what they choose, it then shows text block to them (with text - eg: if they chose option A then they are shown text block with A information in it, etc). How do I go about making something like this?

1) Is this javascript job?

I dont even know where to start :(

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. I think First of all you need to learn How to Google search. After that you can start writing your plugin. Well Here is the Wordpress Plugin Handbook https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/. As it states

> The Plugin Developer Handbook is a resource for all things WordPress
>   plugins. Whether you’re new to WordPress plugin development, or you’re
>   an experienced plugin developer, you should be able to find the answer
>   to many of your plugin-related questions right here.

Good Luck